# Sheets date formula help

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Im trying to find a way to input a due date associated with a task with a column next to it with check marks that can clicked once the task is complete, if it doesnt get checked by the due date I'd like that cell to change to past due. Can anyone help me figure this out?[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind creating a new column you can do something like this:
[image]